# How do you call an ajax function from within the same function?

Tags: ajax, jquery, polling

I want to create a polling ajax function that calls the same function all over again if a certain condition is met. How would I do this? I'm using JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use jQuery's ajax callback function like this?

```
function myFunc(condition) {

    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:ajaxUrl,
        data:dataObject,
        success:function(response) {
            if (!condition) {
                myFunc(newCondition);
            }
        }
    }); 
}
myFunc();
```

This will call the same function over and over until the condition is true.

jQuery's ajax reference page: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: It will also stop calling it if `condition` is true in the callback, right?

Comment: Right, do some logic based on the response to determine if you need to do the ajax request again. But keep in mind that doing a loop of tons of ajax requests might not be good for your server.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
(function poll() {   
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success:function(response) {
            if (!condition_is_met) {
                poll();
            }
        }
    });
})(); //This calls the poll function inmediatly
```

If you want to be executed exactly after certain time, you could do:

```
setInterval(function poll() {   
  if(condition_is_met){
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success:function(response) {
            //your code here
        }
    });
  }
}, 5000); //Execute every 5 seconds
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could write a javascript function to make your ajax call and set an interval for it. Using [window.setInterval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536749%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).